# Is lineSpacing a property of UILabel?

Tags: swift, uilabel, subclass

I have a subclass of UILabel with a property `lineSpacing` setup like so:

```
var lineSpacing = CGFloat(20.0)
```

When I have this here it pushes up the text, even though it isn't used for anything, I removed all the code except for that property:

```
class CustomLabel : UILabel {
    var lineSpacing = CGFloat(20.0)
}
```

and it is still pushed up, I changed the name of the property and it fixed it, I was just wondering where this is coming from as I can't access `lineSpacing` from a `UILabel`

```
regularLabel.lineSpacing
```

gives an error.

Comment: Also observed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32008465/linespacing-property-inside-uilabel-doesnt-work-as-expected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `UILabel` has an undocumented, non-public `lineSpacing` property.  You can see it in this header file that was created from the runtime Objective-C metadata:

https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UILabel.h

Since it's not public, overriding it (even accidentally) may cause Apple to reject your app if you submit it to the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of implementing your own line spacing code (or if you really wanted to override that property), you could use the built in private property by creating a protocol exposing the property:

```
@objc protocol UILabelPrivate {
    var lineSpacing: Int {get set}
}

let label = UILabel()
let privateLabel = unsafeBitCast(label, UILabelPrivate.self)

privateLabel.lineSpacing = 2

label.valueForKey("lineSpacing") // 2
```

This effectively creates an "interface" exposing the normally private `lineSpacing` property.

Comment: It would be simpler to just use KVO: `label.setValue(2, forKey: "lineSpacing")` and less likely to trigger App Store rejection.

Comment: Wow more than I needed, the property was called line spacing due to the spacing of drawn lines in the view and their spacing. I guess this might be confusing in a Label view.